# Pandas transpose on double column index

Tags: python, pandas, transpose

I have a data frame like the one below

[image: before]

And I want to transform it like following

[image: after]

Its a Double column index Transformation and I don't mind which of price/quantity, or date is the first level of column index.  I think date is top and splits for price/quantity but couldn't create the table like this here.Its a data frame with about a million lines and all dates of year, so do you have any idea for the most efficient code to to this? Empty cells could also be 0s

SAMPLE DATA

| CID | PROD_ID | PRICE | DATE | QUANTITY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | x | 1 | 31-12-20 | 5 |
| 123 | x | 1 | 1-1-21 | 5 |
| 123 | x | 1 | 2-1-21 | 7 |
| 123 | y | 2 | 2-1-21 | 11 |
| 789 | z | 5 | 1-1-21 | 22 |
| 256 | a | 4 | 1-1-21 | 9 |
| 324 | b | 4 | 1-1-21 | 16 |
| 789 | z | 5.5 | 2-1-21 | 22 |
| 324 | a | 4.5 | 2-1-21 | 23 |
| 324 | e | 8 | 2-1-21 | 3 |

Comment: Please provide your sample data in text instead of picture here.  Probably your question was downvoted because of this.  More importantly, contributors here are less willing to answer your question if can't get your sample data by copy and paste for testing.

Comment: Use `df = df.pivot(['CID','PROD_ID'], 'DATE')`

Comment: @jezrael Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

Comment: Then use `df = df.pivot_table(index=['CID','PROD_ID'], columns='DATE')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pandas.pivot_table`

```
pd.pivot_table(
    df,
    values=['PRICE', 'QUANTITY'],
    index=['CID', 'PROD_ID'],
    columns=['DATE'],
    aggfunc=sum
)
```

Output

```
             PRICE                 QUANTITY                
DATE        1-1-21 2-1-21 31-12-20   1-1-21 2-1-21 31-12-20
CID PROD_ID                                                
123 x          1.0    1.0      1.0      5.0    7.0      5.0
    y          NaN    2.0      NaN      NaN   11.0      NaN
256 a          4.0    NaN      NaN      9.0    NaN      NaN
324 a          NaN    4.5      NaN      NaN   23.0      NaN
    b          4.0    NaN      NaN     16.0    NaN      NaN
    e          NaN    8.0      NaN      NaN    3.0      NaN
789 z          5.0    5.5      NaN     22.0   22.0      NaN
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. And how do I access a cell here?

Comment: Use multiindexing `df.loc[(123, 'x'), ('PRICE', '1-1-21')]`